Handling [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM] Error in Mocha Tests with TypeScript Compilation
I’m integrating end-to-end tests into my Angular project and using a stack that includes Selenium, Chai, and Mocha. Since Mocha requires JavaScript, I compile my TypeScript files into JavaScript with the command:
tsc -p e2e && mocha dist/e2e/tests --reporter mochawesome

However, I’m facing an Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM] in the generated JavaScript files when running the tests. The issue seems to stem from the fact that the .js files are regenerated every time I run the tests, which prevents me from making persistent changes to them as a workaround.
The complete error message:
Exception during run: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Projects\Project_name\node_modules\chai\chai.js from C:\Projects\Project_name\dist\e2e\tests\myTest.spec.js not supported.
Instead change the require of chai.js in C:\Projects\Project_name\dist\e2e\tests\myTest.spec.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\Project_name\dist\e2e\tests\myTest.spec.js:3:16)
    at async formattedImport (C:\Projects\Project_name\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:9:14)
    at async exports.requireOrImport (C:\Projects\Project_name\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:42:28)  
    at async exports.loadFilesAsync (C:\Projects\Project_name\node_modules\mocha\lib\nodejs\esm-utils.js:100:20)  
    at async singleRun (C:\Projects\Project_name\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:125:3)
    at async exports.handler (C:\Projects\Project_name\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:370:5) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

I attempted to create a Mocha configuration file named mocha.opts in my project’s root directory to enable ESM support. The following entry was added to the mocha.opts file:
--allow-esm

Also I tried to modify the TypeScript compilation process by adjusting the TypeScript compiler options (tsc) to handle the import of ESMs, such as chai.js. In the compilerOptions of the tsconfig.json file located in my e2e directory, I included:
{
  "moduleResolution": "node", // Enables Node.js module resolution
  "esModuleInterop": true     // Enables interoperability between CommonJS and ESM modules
}

Lastly, I tried using npx in place of npm.
None of the three solutions mentioned above worked to solve the error, and, of course, modifying the generated JavaScript files is not an option.

Can you try using chai version 4? I encountered a similar problem after upgrading to v5
